# Karatedsl JSON-Schema failed with response "all key-values did not match"

Tags: karate, json-schema-validator

I have tried a feature from karatedsl like json-schema...
For example I have a file json contain :

```js
{
  "level": "info",
  "event": "biller.purchase",
  "credential": "MallOn_v2",
  "package": "aaaa",
  "id": 41658,
  "customer_id": "088810000000",
  "elapsed_time": 201,
  "transactionbillerid": 39124,
  "paramrequest": {
    "amount": "10000",
    "customer_id": "088810000000",
    "partner_name": "MallOn_v2"
  },
  "parsedresponse": {
    "desc": "SUCCESS",
    "rescode": "0",
    "status": "success",
    "transactionID": "511644294"
  },
  "responsecode": "00",
  "price": 10000,
  "amount": 10000,
  "time": "2018-11-29T19:06:04.757550"
}
```

and I match that son like this :

- def json = read('biller_log2.json')
- Then match json ==

```js
"""
        {
          "level": '#string',
          "event": '#string',
          "credential": '#string',
          "package": '#string',
          "id": 'number',
          "customer_id": '#string',
          "elapsed_time": '#number',
          "transactionbillerid": '#number',
          "paramrequest": {
            "amount": '#string',
            "customer_id": '#string',
            "partner_name": '#string'
          },
          "parsedresponse": {
            "desc": '#string',
            "rescode": '#string',
            "status": '#string',
            "transactionID": '#string'
          },
          "responsecode": '#string',
          "price": '#number',
          "amount": '#number',
          "time": '#string'
      }
    """
```

but I get error with message "reason : all key-values did not match", how to fix it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema has one incorrect value causing this failure,

`id` should be `"#number"` not `"number"`

Modified Schema:

```
""" 
{
 "level": '#string',
  "event": '#string', 
  "credential": '#string',
  "package": '#string',
  "id": '#number', 
  "customer_id": '#string',     
  "elapsed_time": '#number',
  "transactionbillerid": '#number',
  "paramrequest": { 
  "amount": '#string', 
  "customer_id": '#string',      
  "partner_name": '#string' 
  }, 
 "parsedresponse": {
   "desc": '#string',
   "rescode": '#string', 
   "status": '#string', 
   "transactionID": '#string'
 }, 
 "responsecode": '#string',
 "price": '#number', 
 "amount": '#number', 
 "time": '#string' 
} 
"""
```

Comment: ooooh.. I seee XD